# writing multiple lines to a file using multiple fprintf statement vs con-cat multiple lines and then write to a file using one fprintf statement?

Tags: c, linux

My application (written in C) has to dequeue 500 strings and write them to a text file. I can  dequeue every single string and use a separate `fprintf` statement to write each one to a file, or I can concatenate all the dequeued strings into one string and then write that long concatenated string into a file with single `fprintf` statement. Which approach is better?

Approach 1:

```
i = 0;
while (i < 500)
{
    memset(cdr_info, 0, sizeof(cdr_info));
    de_cdrQueue(cdr_info);
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", cdr_info);
    i++;
}
```

Approach 2:

```
char cdr[10000];
i = 0;
while (i < 500)
{
    memset(cdr_info, 0, sizeof(cdr_info));
    de_cdrQueue(cdr_info);
    strcat(cdr,"\n");
    strcat(cdr, cdr_info);
    i++;
}
fprintf(fp, "%s\n", cdr_info);
```

Comment: Using `strcat()` like that leads to quadratic behaviour.  Don’t use that technique, even if you are going to use the concatenated string more than once. (Keep a record of where the end of the string is so you can copy directly to the correct location.) If you’re only going to use the concatenated string once, don’t use concatenation. The first method is probably better in most circumstances.

Comment: I shall not use strcat() to concat rather I shall use snprintf to concat 500 strings. But my confusion is when I use approach 1 need file operation 500 times(fprintf) but in approach 2 I need 1 file operation(fprintf) to do the same task. So approach 2 should be faster than approach 1(because approach 2 need less file operations). Am I right or not?

Comment: Be careful with `snprintf()` too — there are ways of using it equivalent to using `strcat()`, and there are others that are not.  Beware of the requirements about 'no overlap' between the target string and the arguments for `snprintf()`.  Using `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s%s\n", buffer, new_info)` is verboten by the standard, though your compiler may or may not spot the problem.  Contrast with `snprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer), "%s\n", new_info)`.  Avoid calling `strlen()` twice as shown.

Comment: Also note that there's a decent chance that the 'all at once' technique is slower than the 'bit at a time' technique because your big string requires more memory allocation than lots of smaller strings (but it is conceivable that multiple system calls to write is slower one).  YMMV — in case of doubt, measure whether there's a performance difference.

Answer (score 4):

One of the properties of stdio streams, especially when connected to files, is that they buffer input and output and then write it in large pieces.  Thus, unless you've interfered with the buffering of `fp`, you *automatically* get I/O behavior similar to approach 2 from approach 1.

Furthermore, you can control the size of the buffer via [`setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf), so if you want a 10000-byte buffer then you can ensure that, allowing an approach 1 solution with I/O semantics even more similar to your approach 2.  Unless you want the concatenated string for more than just printing it, there's pretty much no reason to prefer approach 2 when approach 1 is feasible.